# How to restart my java program automatically if it gets killed?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, java, upstart

I am running my runnable jar in linux machine (machineA) as shown below. In the runnable Jar, I have a java program which sends email to me every 15 mniutes.

```
/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar abc.jar config.properties &
```

As soon as I start my `abc.jar` like above, it will be running in the background and there is a class which will keep on sending me email every 15 minutes. I am using Scheduler in my java program which is a thread which wakes up every 15 minutes and send me an email.

Now everything is working fine. Suppose `machineA` got restarted for some reason or `abc.jar` got killed for whatever reason, then I am looking for a way so that my `abc.jar` gets started in the background again automatically.

So I decided to use upstart feature in Ubunutu as I am running Ubuntu 12.04 - And here is my config file  -

```
#/etc/init/testlnp.conf

#sudo start testlnp
#sudo stop testlnp

start on runlevel [2345]
stop on runlevel [016]

chdir /export/home/david/tester
respawn

post-stop script
  sleep 30
end script

limit nofile 8092 8092
setuid david
exec /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar abc.jar config.properties &
```

I have my `abc.jar` file in this directory `/export/home/david/tester`. Now I started my java program like this one time -

```
sudo start testlnp
```

And it started fine, I can see through `ps aux | grep java` -

```
david@machineA:~$ ps aux | grep java
david 130691 38.5  0.0 33906208 58636 ?      Sl   19:24   0:01 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar abc.jar config.properties
david   131029  0.0  0.0   8100   936 pts/2    S+   19:24   0:00 grep --color=auto java
```

Now after some time, I did `ps aux | grep java` again and I saw like this -  Meaning multiple instances of my `abc.jar` program? This is what I am not able to understand why it happened?

```
david@slc4b03c-8ixd:~$ ps aux | grep java
david   1746  4.5  0.0 33906208 57808 ?      Sl   19:25   0:01 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar abc.jar config.properties
david   2143 73.0  0.0 33906208 57992 ?      Sl   19:25   0:01 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar abc.jar config.properties
david     2180  0.0  0.0   8100   936 pts/2    S+   19:25   0:00 grep --color=auto java
david 130691  2.5  0.0 33906208 57492 ?      Sl   19:24   0:01 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar abc.jar config.properties
```

My main aim is to restart abc.jar again if my machine gets restarted or abc.jar gets killed for whatever reason? How do I achieve this? Is there anything wrong I am doing with upstart?

**UPDATE:-**

This is what I got for PPID -

```
david@machineA:~$ ps aux | grep java
david  18454  4.5  0.0 33906208 57520 ?      Sl   20:01   0:01 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar abc.jar config.properties
david  18692 27.3  0.0 33906208 57788 ?      Sl   20:01   0:01 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64/bin/java -jar abc.jar config.properties
david    18779  0.0  0.0   8096   940 pts/2    S+   20:02   0:00 grep --color=auto java


david@machineA:~$ ps  xao pid,ppid,pgid,sid,comm | grep java
 18454      1  18453  18453 java
 18692      1  18691  18691 java
```

Comment: I'd be interested in seeing a ps indicating the PID as well as the PPID.

Comment: @mdpc In my ps PID is already there right or I missed anything?

Comment: ok...what about the PPID?  What I am looking for is the fact that perhaps you have multiple instances because the parent is spinning off forks of itself which sometimes manifests itself like this.

Comment: How to find out about PPID? Is there any command you want me to run?

Comment: Use appropriate options to the PS command.  See the man page for more on your particular distribution.

Comment: @mdpc updated the question with details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get rid of the `&`. That makes it fork into the background, Upstart thinks the process died, then spawns a new one. Just have the exec line without the ampersand.

Comment: aahh.. Let me try this out. But doesn't upstart internally checks the pid of the process and make sure if it is not running then start it back again?

Comment: Right but it thinks the pid is, say 4000, but it is really 4001 because the process was forked off.

Comment: Still trying to understand this, sorry if I missed any basic stuff : if it thinks that pid is 4000 which will still be running right? then why it starts 4001 then?

Comment: It thinks the PID is n, but the pid of the actual running app is something different (usually n+1 or n+2). So then it starts yet another instance, which will have a PID greater than the first started app.

Answer (score 1):

`crontab -e`, then add following item

```
* * * * * a=`ps aux | grep abc.jar | grep -v grep | wc -l`; test $a -eq 0 && java -j /path/to/abc.jar
```

Comment: It seems like you could simplify this: `ps aux | grep -q "[a]bc.jar" || java -j /path/to/abc.jar`. The command `grep "[a]bc.jar"` matches `abc.jar`, but not itself, so you don't need to `grep -v grep`. `grep -q` is quiet; it doesn't write any output (so it's like `> /dev/null`). You don't need to look at the output from `grep`; all you need to do is look at its exit status.

Answer (score 0):

See also daemontools (not the virtual CD mount software): https://cr.yp.to/daemontools.html

Comment: Could you expand on this mainly-a-link-Answer with how the OP would *use* daemontools to solve their problem?